# SQL - Identify a default row

Tags: sql, database-design

#### Context

I would like to know the best practice for this kind of problem.

I have two table: X and Y. Table Y has a foreign_key to table X so X has many Y. When I fetch something in table X, I need the associated rows of table Y. I will also need to fetch the default Y value for one X.

#### Option 1

Should I set boolean column on table Y with isDefault and constraint that enforce that there is only one default for one relation to X (fk_to_X and isDefault)

#### Option 2

Should I make a foreign_key on table X to table Y (FKDefault_Y_ID) that would contain the ID of the default Y row?

#### Example 1

X has many Y. I need to found the default value in the Y values by using either option 1 or option 2.

#### Example 2

It's just like a preference value. I have a select box with many choices. I need to set a default choice when the select box is loaded. So I fetch every Y for X. When the "form" is saved, I fetch the default Y row for that X and save that value.

Comment: Can you send your tables DDL and some data and desired result?

Comment: @Nico: Instead of 'if there is row, I must use a default', do you mean 'I must use a default if *no* row is found'? In which case, I would put the default value in the X table.

Comment: @No'amNewman I clarified the question

Comment: @MohsenHeydari I've added some example to clarify thing a little bit.

Comment: How does option 2 enforce that there can't be multiple Y with the same default value? You _have_ to use option 1, surely.

Comment: @Ben It's one default for each row of X. X can have multiple Y, and one of the Y has to be a default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I have understood the problem:
 *We have a parent table called A that have child records in table B, and we need to have a **single child** in B tagged to be the default child for a given A.* 
As I know if you use `Option 1`, having a cardinal check constraint is not possible in RDBMS, you will need to use trigger like mechanism, that is not appreciated.
Another objection to have `isDefault` column in B table is that, naturally having a default is an attribute of A.
I will use a null-able foreign key in A table from B.

Answer (score 1):

I have to say that I don't understand your examples, but if you have a single default Y per X then I'd definitely go with Option 2. It guarantees in a natural way the uniqueness of the default in a way that is very difficult to achieve robustly via Option 1.

In response to Ben's comment:

> > How does option 2 enforce that there can't be multiple Y with the same default value?

If there was a requirement that a Y row could be the default for only one X row, then Option 2 would still be viable as a unique constraint could be placed on the "default Y ID" column in table X.